# ':' from inserting url into db causing error

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to insert some urls. The string is successfully transferred to the query however the colon in the url causes it to fail.

```
discord_link_list = (re.findall(r'(https?://discord.gg[^(.+?)\']+)', link_list))

for link in discord_link_list:
    query = (
        f"INSERT INTO crawler_invitelink (inviteLink)\n"
        f"VALUES (  %s )" %(link)
    )
    dict_cur.execute(query)
    print(query)
```

psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 2: VALUES (  https://discord.gg/FAFVJxB )

this is the error message that is received

Comment: Maybe it's because you have to surround the value inside quotes (e.g., `"INSERT INTO crawler_invitelink (inviteLink) VALUES ( '%s' )"`.

Comment: Now I get the error "column does not exist"

Comment: print query to see it and use it directly in database - using some DB viewer/editor. Database may display more information about problem.

Comment: Maybe you should use preferred method `execute(query, link)` instead of creating query manually.

Comment: I figured out a way, thank you guys for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the help, for anyone looking at this now, this solved my issue. basically ascribed the links to a dictionary and then called the value only into the query

```
for link in discord_link_list:
    invite_link = link
    data.append({ "invite_link" : invite_link })

print(data)

for link in data:
    query = (
        f"INSERT INTO crawler_invitelink (discord_link)\n"
        f"VALUES ( '%s' )" %(  link['invite_link']  )
    )
    dict_cur.execute(query)
    print(query)
```